# Display LilyPond fret diagrams next to chord names instead of below

Tags: chords, lilypond

I am trying to display chord diagrams with LilyPond to the side of the chord names.

By default, LilyPond renders the diagram below the chord name like so:
[image: chord name directly above fretboard diagram]

but I want them to be side by side like so:
[image: chord name on the left of fretboard diagram].

How can I accomplish this with LilyPond?

So far I am able to get the following output, but the diagrams are too far from the staff:
[image]

The ideal state would look something like this. The diagrams and chord names stick close together and also close to the staff below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the alignment direction of the fretboard diagrams with:
`\override FretBoard.align-dir = #LEFT`

And you can override the horizontal and vertical offsets with:
`\override FretBoard.X-offset = #5` &
`\override FretBoard.Y-offset = #5`

To get the chord names and fretboard diagrams to sit to the top of the staff/tablature you will also need to use:
`\override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-affinity = #DOWN`

All together you'll get something like this:

```
\version "2.24.0"

\include "predefined-guitar-fretboards.ly"

theChords = {
    \set chordChanges = ##t
    \chordmode {
        a1:m | c | g | g | \break
        e | e | a:m | c |
    }
}

\score {
    <<
        \new FretBoards {
            \override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-affinity = #DOWN
            \override FretBoard.align-dir = #LEFT
            \override FretBoard.X-offset = #5
            \override FretBoard.Y-offset = #5
            
            \theChords
        }
        \new ChordNames {
            \theChords
        }
        \new TabStaff {
            \predefinedFretboardsOn
            \theChords
        }
    >>
}
```

(You might need to adjust the horizontal offset value depending on how many measures per line you have.)

[image: Tablature with chords, chord names above, and fretboard diagrams above and offset to the right.]

Comment: Thank you! This is close to what I want. But when I try to move the chord name lower and closer to the diagram (similar to the shared image in my question), the diagram keeps moving up, further away from the staff and I end up having similar amount of vertical space, which I was trying to avoid. Any idea how to avoid this effect? I tried to use ```\override FretBoard.align-dir = #LEFT```
 ```\override FretBoard.X-offset = #6```
 ```\override FretBoard.Y-offset = #6```

Comment: @JAV I've added a Y-offset to my answer, but I'm not sure if this is quite right yet.  Are you saying that you want the chord names and the fretboard diagrams to be even closer to the tablature?

Comment: Thank youm this is awesome! :) When I try out the code from your example, my result looks a bit worse - the diagrams are a bit too far and the chord names too. I updated my answer to display what I currently get. I am on version 2.20.0. Maybe that could play some role?

Comment: @JAV Thanks for the image, I found what was going wrong.  I've added `\override VerticalAxisGroup.staff-affinity = #DOWN` to the other overrides, and I think that solves the problem.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. What is the `staff-affinity` property doing? Also is it possible to override the same properties for the chord names? In the example image that I posted, the chord name and chord diagram are centered to be above the place where the chord should be played. In the current version, the chord name is right above the place where it should be played and the diagram is shifted to the left. It could be possible to also move the chord name to the left a bit so that the chord note below is in between the name and the diagram.

Comment: @JAV If you want to change the chord names horizontal position, use something like: `\override ChordName.X-offset = #-4`, inside the `CordNames` block. (Then you might want to remove the fretboard's `X-offset`.)

Comment: The chord name offsets work like a charm. I tried to reduce the horizontal space between the chord name and the diagram - the modified chords such as `Cm` or `A7` show up close, but the base chords such as `C` or `A` keep an extra character space instead of sticking close to the diagram -- see eg. in your example - the `C` is further from the diagram than, say, `Am`. I tried to use `extra-spacing-width` and `self-alignment-X` to align the chord names to the right, but it had no effect. Any idea how this could be done? Also how to find all properties available on an object in the docs?

Comment: @JAV You might find something on one of the "internals", e.g. https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/internals/chordnames. Or maybe you are looking for a property that is inherited from another class/object/context. I have trouble understanding the internals myself.

Comment: Thank you, I'll post some results if I manage to figure this out.