# How to create a custom markup for chord names in lilypond

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

I am trying to display chord names left from the chord diagrams in lilypond. Based on answers in [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/132055/94866) I was able to offset the positions of the diagrams and respective chord names, but the result is inconsistent across staves. Sometimes the chord name is too far or jumps above the diagram.

[image]

Instead, I was able to get a consistent behavior by using note markup as follows:

```
  c^\markup{
    \column{\hspace #0.05 \vspace #0.5 "C" }
    \column{
      \override #`(fret-diagram-details . ((handedness . ,LEFT)))
      \fret-diagram "6-x;5-3-3;4-2-2;3-o;2-1;1-o;"
    }
  }
```

which gives a nicely placed chord name in front of the diagram and its consistent accross staves. [image]

My question is, how to make this makrup more automated? I do not want to re-define default fret diagrams for every chorded note in every song and have this complex syntax inside melody definitions. Ideally, it is possible to overwrite the behavior of chordmode to automatically display chords with this markup and there is no need for note-based markup. A solution that uses some makro/template/function directly in the melody definitions like I do here, but is less verbose is also acceptable - for example `c^\chord_diag{"c"}`. Any ideas are very welcome. Just getting to know lilypond for a few weeks now.